# Cannot Resolve Method 'deleteCharAt()'

Tags: java, android

What is the alternative for 'deleteCharAt()'? Is there a library?

I wanted to delete a specific character on a String.

Here is my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText name1;
        EditText name2;
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){


                EditText name1;
                EditText name2;
                TextView textout2;
                TextView textout;
                int sum;

                name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                name2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                int totalLength = 0;
                int total;
                String inputText1 = name1.getText().toString();
                String inputText2 = name2.getText().toString();
                totalLength = name1.length() + name2.length();

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT,0, 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++)
                {

                    char ch = inputText1.charAt(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < name2.length(); j++)
                    {     
                        if (ch == inputText2.charAt(j))
                        {
                            inputText1.deleteCharAt();
                            inputText2.deleteCharAt();

                        }

                    }

                }


        });



    }
```

Comment: you can use StringBuilder class which has the method deleteCharAt and then convert it to a String using its toString method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change these lines:

```
StringBuilder inputText1 = new StringBuilder(name1.getText().toString());
StringBuilder inputText2 = new StringBuilder(name2.getText().toString());
```

StringBuilder class has a deleteCharAt() method(exactly what you are looking for).

To get a String object from StringBuilder, simply use:

```
String str = inputText1.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your string in a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(yourString);
```

There you can use the [deleteChatAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getText()` with an `EditText` returns an `Editable` (ie, an editable `String`). An `Editable` does not have a [`deleteCharAt (int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int)) method like `StringBuilder` does. However, you can use its [`delete (int st, int en)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#delete(int,%20int)) method as an alternate, where `st` is the start index and `en` is the end index (exclusive). So if you want to delete a single `char` then make `en = st + 1`.

```
int index = 4;

EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Editable text = myEditText.getText();
text.delete(index, index + 1); // delete char at index
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Remove(Int32, Int32)
```

It may be use as alternative for `deleteCharAt()`

The above code returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in the current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.

Comment: `Remove(Int32, Int32)` is not a method of `EditText`, `Editable`, `StringBuilder`, or `String`. I'm not sure how it is supposed to be an alternative.